# Contract Coin failed to track a contract

Tags: team-fortress-2

So since the Gun Mettle update rolled out, I have completed four different contracts, three of them for specific classes and one for a specific Gun Mettle map. Although, something isn't quite right.

**Even though I have completed four contracts, my Contract Coin shows the stats from only three of them.**

So is this just a weird bug? Can this be fixed?

Comment: Could be a syncing issue. If it hasn't appeared in a couple of days it's probably best to contact Valve about this.

Comment: yeah probably best to contact Valve then I'd say. (report back when you get a response) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [2015 July 15 update](http://store.steampowered.com/news/17567/) (yesterday's update) included this in its patch notes:

- Fixed a case where Campaign Coins weren't displaying the correct stats based on the number of submitted contracts

  - Everyone affected by this bug has received the maximum contract points (including bonus points) for the missing contracts

So yes, it was a bug.